# UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning: multiple calls to interruptibleAnimator?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uiviewpropertyanimator

I just spent the last few hours tracking down a bug that happened to be located in a transition driver object, **where the `interruptibleAnimator` method was called several times**, where:

1. a `UIViewPropertyAnimator` completion closure contained a reference to `[unowned self]` to complete the transition context passed by its transition controller with `self.context.completeTransition(true)`
2. the transition controller, which implements `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning` and is a `UINavigationControllerDelegate`, passed the context via its `animate` method

   ```
   extension NavigationTransitionController: UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning {

   func transitionDuration(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning?) -> TimeInterval {
       return transitionDuration
   }

   func animationEnded(_ transitionCompleted: Bool) {

       // Clean up our helper object and any additional state
       transitionDriver = nil
   }

   func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
       transitionDriver = TransitionDriver(context: transitionContext, duration: transitionDuration)
       interruptibleAnimator(using: transitionContext).startAnimation()
   }

   func interruptibleAnimator(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) -> UIViewImplicitlyAnimating {
       return transitionDriver!.transitionAnimator
   }
   ```

Unless I am missing something very basic here, I have no idea why the transition controller would make more than 1 call to the `interruptibleAnimator` method.

**My structure was inspired by what Apple presented [here in their WWDC 2016 talk](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/216/); if you download, put a breakpoint and launch their Photo Transitioning app you can see for yourself that this method is called twice for the same transition in their case.**

Could somebody enlighten me as to whether I am chasing a ghost or if this is a legit weird behavior?

Answer (score 2):

Apple states in the 'header docs' for `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning`:

```
/// A conforming object implements this method if the transition it creates can
/// be interrupted. For example, it could return an instance of a
/// UIViewPropertyAnimator. It is expected that this method will return the same
/// instance for the life of a transition.
@available(iOS 10.0, *)
optional public func interruptibleAnimator(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) -> UIViewImplicitlyAnimating
```

The same is stated at minute 29:34 in [WWDC Session 2016](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/216/). The sample implementation on the slide at minute 27:33 seems to be misleading / wrong.

The reason why it is called multiple times is beyond my knowledge.